# Cannot start the specific sub-System Settings items from Applications launcher (Slingshot)

Tags: slingshot

The Applications launcher can show and should start the different specific settings under System Settings.

In my case they **do not** start if clicked.

[image]

'Systems Settings' can be started in this way, but not its sub-settings.

---

Update after the subsettings have been completely absent in Slingshot but then appeared again after update, and a [post is saying this was fixed](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10620/170):

There are still many sub-settings that are not accessible from slingshot.

Comment: When I search for control panel plugs in the slingshot applications menu, none of them show up.

Comment: @Seth - Right! Maybe they have decided to fix it by removing completely  the non-responsive entries.

Comment: Some plugins have reappeared in applications menu search, but I noticed also that several are still absent including desktop, language & region, notifications, displays, etc

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a changement in Switchboard (the System Settings) application. We might report this as a bug, however, I guess now the `slingshot-launcher` should open `settings:///` URIs instead of calling `switchboard -o` (as it does for now).

Answer (score 2):

A fix [has been committed](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/slingshot/trunk) to address this issue. An update was issued as of January 3rd, 2017

Comment: updated question

Comment: only a few of the items appear now (8 feb.2017) in Slingshot

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1643014
Fix seems released, not sure when we'll get it through the updates.