# Commands to start sub-Settings?

Tags: release-loki, settings, slingshot, command-line

I rarely use most of the Settings, but those that I use more often (Shortcuts, Startup applications, Printers) I want them accessed really fast.

For example I would like to be able to open with only one click or short-key the Shortcuts window.

[image]

At some point the subsections of Settings were accessible through Slingshot, but [not anymore](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/9903/170).

An ideal way for me would be to know the commands that would trigger at least some of them and then create a shortcut or a dock launcher for those.

Are there such commands?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this issue has been fixed since, you can launch sub-settings via Slingshot again. (cf. [Cannot start the specific sub-System Settings items from Applications launcher (Slingshot)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9903/cannot-start-the-specific-sub-system-settings-items-from-applications-launcher))

Comment: at the present only a part of the sub-settings are available: see updated linked question

Answer (score 0):

That's not a quite what I asked, but... 
At least one sub-setting (Startup) is administer also by another (a bit under-the hood) tool: `gnome-session-properties` (of the `gnome-session-bin` package, installed by default) - more [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/351/170). - So, `gnome-session-properties` can be the command for that.